# Equivelant of node_type_load() for entity bundles

Tags: entities

If I know the entity type and bundle, I want to load the bundle object with its settings. Drupal core has this for nodes, but is there any way to do it for entities?

See `node_type_load()` in core:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_load/7

**EDIT:** So to elaborate, I'm asking about a way to load up the data about the entity bundle, not a specific entity.

E.g.

```
var_dump(node_type_load('page'));

object(stdClass)[628]
  public 'type' => string 'page' (length=4)
  public 'name' => string 'Page' (length=4)
  public 'base' => string 'node_content' (length=12)
  public 'module' => string 'node' (length=4)
  public 'description' => string 'Use <em>pages</em> for your static content.' (length=43)
  public 'help' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'has_title' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'title_label' => string 'Title' (length=5)
  public 'custom' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'modified' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'locked' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'disabled' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'orig_type' => string 'page' (length=4)
  public 'disabled_changed' => boolean false
```

Comment: have you tried entity_get_property_info() like i suggested below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [entity_get_property_info()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.property.inc/function/entity_get_property_info/7) for example

```
var_dump(entity_get_property_info('node'));
```

Bundles are a keyed array within the result and they contain a keyed array of the fields and their settings.

Other information about the bundles other than field properties, such as menu callback etc, can be obtained using [entity_get_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_get_info/7) where the bundles as keyed array within the result contains other non-field info.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am not 100% sure what you need here. However, as nodes are entities there will be a way to load other entities. You have [entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7) for example. If this is not what you need could you elaborate?

Comment: Have updated question with example output of `node_type_load()`.

Comment: Ok, are there particular settings from the node_type_load var_dump that you need. You can load up a lot of information with [EntityMetadataWrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers). Depending on what you are trying to do with the information [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) might help as well. Let us know which properties, settings etc. you are looking for and we can help you narrow it down.

Comment: For example: `$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', NULL, array('bundle' => 'page'));` has a lot of information, possibly way too much for your needs.